# function to duplicate / create on click html elements with number order ( ID / name ) using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, tags

i need function to create or duplicate HTML elements on button click but need to be their **ID** / **name** different.
example:

```
<p>
    <input id="skill1" type="text" class="text_field" placeholder="Skill"
         name="skill1" value="">
</p>
<p>
    <input id="skill2" type="text" class="text_field" placeholder="Skill"
         name="skill2" value="">
</p>
<p>
    <input id="skill3" type="text" class="text_field" placeholder="Skill"
         name="skill3" value="">
</p>
```

i have this code but its long and can't create with different id / name

```
function createSkill() {
    var elemP = document.createElement("p");
    var elemIn = document.createElement("input");
    elemIn.setAttribute("type", "text");
    elemIn.setAttribute("value", "");
    elemIn.setAttribute("placeholder", "Skill");
    elemIn.setAttribute("class", "text_field");
    elemP.appendChild(elemIn);
    document.getElementById("skill_info").appendChild(elemP);
}
```

Comment: who is calling createSkill function

Comment: a button in skills section div , the skill input field is being added , but i need to add with different id or name each time the button clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one may help

**

```js
var i = 0;
function createSkill() {
i++
elemIn.setAttribute('id','skill'+i);
elemIn.setAttribute('name','skill'+i);
}
```

**